# Solve linear system, find all values of t that there exists only one solution of the system

Tags: linear-algebra

$x,y$ are variables and $t$ is a parameter:

$2x-yt-3t=0$ and $ty=9t-x$

1. find all values of t that there exists only one solution
2. solve the system be using the inverse matrix way

Comment: So I  did a bit of organize: $2x+(-y-3)t=0$ and $x+(y-9)t=0$, and then $2(y-9)-(-y-3)\neq 0$ which gives us $y\neq5$, is this correct? Am I on the right track? And what should do for part.2?

Answer (score 1):

both represent Linear Eqations. i.e equation of a straight line
y=(2x/t) -3
y=(-x/t)+9
both will intersect if slopes of them are not equal
means t belongs to R -{o}